# Why doesn't the "assertSelectorExists()" assertion show the failure message that I specify?

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit, symfony-panther

I'm trying to show a custom message (the URL being tested) when a PHPUnit 9.5.11 test fails. in my Symfony 4.4 app.

The class is simple:

```
class BaseTestCase extends PantherTestCase
```

In my test, I've:

```
$client = static::createPantherClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$this->assertSelectorExists('.some-class', $url); // <- this should display the tested $url, since the second argument is supposed to be the message to show on failure
```

But when the test fails, all I get is:

> 1. App\Tests\PropertyListingTest::testListingWithFullQueryString with
>    data set #0 ('') Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException:
>    no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>    selector","selector":".some-class"}   (Session info:
>    headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)

What's going on here? If I run this:

```
$this->assertEquals("a", "b", "!!!!TEST FAILED!!!!");
```

It works as expected:

> !!!!TEST FAILED!!!! Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
> --- Expected
> +++ Actual @@ @@
> -'a'
> +'b'

Comment: Are you sure your `$url` not empty at `$this->assertSelectorExists('.some-class', $url);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour actually looks like a bug to me.

Because if you look at what `assertSelectorExists` does internally (see below)...

```
public static function assertSelectorExists(string $selector, string $message = ''): void
{
    $client = self::getClient();

    if ($client instanceof PantherClient) {
        $element = self::findElement($selector); // NoSuchElementException is thrown here
        self::assertNotNull($element, $message); // so the message is never used
        
        return;
    }

    self::assertNotEmpty($client->getCrawler()->filter($selector));
}
```

...you'll notice that it expects `findElement` to return null in case if no element was found. But the problem is that `findElement` doesn't return null in that case, it throws an exception instead.

To fix this, I would make my own version of assertSelectorExists like this:

```
$client = static::createPantherClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$this->assertSelectorExistsSafe($client, '.some-class', $url);

protected function assertSelectorExistsSafe($client, $selector, $message)
{
    try {
        $element = $client->findElement($client->createWebDriverByFromLocator($selector));
    } catch (\Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException $e) {
        $element = null;
    }
    self::assertNotNull($element, $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your intention right

```
$client = static::createPantherClient();
$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$crawler = $response->getContent();
```

Now the `crawler` variable holds the actual data you get from the `url` variable

It's up to you how to proceed testing this information